# AWT mousePress() and keyPress() don't work as I expect in Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, awt, keypress, minecraft-forge, mousepress

I try to use awt.Robot to programmatically create mouse and key events. The problem is that key events are badly or not treated. 
There is no error message. Here is the code:

```
package com.ClCH38.CC_Macro.TDI;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Tdi {

    Robot robot;
    Tdi tdi;

    public Tdi() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void directInputKey() { 
        try {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);    // Choose slot 1.             Work fine 
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);// Needed to release key
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);    // Choose slot 2.@            
                The item is put in hand, but slot 1 is seems always selected
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);// Needed to release key
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);    // Choose slot 1            Don’t change anything
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);// Needed to release key
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);    // Move player back        Don’t work
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);// Needed to release key
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);//             Place block
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK); // mouse button 3 is for AWT mouse right button
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);//             Don’t work
            Thread.sleep(50);
            robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I work on Mac OS 10.10.9, Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Forge does not process keypresses and mouse events live.

The game runs in "ticks" 20 times a second. All interactions in between are held in buffers.

Mouse events are retrieved from `org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;`

For example what I use for mouse is this:

```
      if(this.isHoveringOverOptionsList) {
            if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0))
                {
                if(this.notThisTick == 0) {
                    this.notThisTick = 20;
                    this.handleClickOnQuestion(mouseX,mouseY);
                }
                }
            else {
                while (this.isHoveringOverOptionsList && Mouse.next())
                {
                    int scroll = Mouse.getEventDWheel();
                    if (scroll != 0)
                    {
                        /** moderation is key **/
                        if      (scroll > 0) scroll = -1;
                        else if (scroll < 0) scroll =  1;
                        this.scrollOptions(scroll);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(this.isHoveringOverTextArea) {
            if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0))
            {
                if(this.notThisTick == 0) {
                    if(this.isHoveringOverLineDownButton) {
                        this.scroll(1);
                        this.notThisTick = 2;
                    }
                    if(this.isHoveringOverLineUpButton) {
                        this.scroll(-1);
                        this.notThisTick = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                while (this.isHoveringOverTextArea && Mouse.next())
                {
                    int scroll = Mouse.getEventDWheel();
                    if (scroll != 0)
                    {
                        /** moderation is key **/
                        if      (scroll > 0) scroll = -1;
                        else if (scroll < 0) scroll =  1;
                        this.scroll(scroll);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So what you ahve to see is how you can add custom items to the mouse buffer.

For how to handle keyboard events I suggest you look at minecrafts GuiChat.java.

It's in the forgeSrc.jar in your eclipse(if you use eclipse)

See where they read their input from, and add your bufferend input to there.

Also, don't use threads! Just fire your event in the TickEvent

```
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.Phase;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.ServerTickEvent;

public class EventHandlerWorld {
    @SubscribeEvent 
    public void calculateAverageTickTime(ServerTickEvent event) {
        if(event.phase == Phase.START) {
            MinecraftServer x = FMLCommonHandler.instance().getMinecraftServerInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. However, what I am interesting in is to use AWT Robot keyPress and mousePress methods to be able to simulate physical input actions. Up to now, I success while using other apps like TextEdit or Page (using delay method to get expected result) but with Minecraft, behaviour is completely unexpected. It is perhaps linked to the fact I use a Mac as I have found there may be problems using AWT Robot on such machine. Have some idea?

Comment: And also I want to send events to the World, not to a GUI. Finally, for now, I am only interested in single player mode

Comment: AWT != lwjgl. you cannot mix those two interchangeably. Also, if you wish to send them to the world, send data packets from the client to the world that have the corresponding events... http://greyminecraftcoder.blogspot.nl/2013/10/packets-from-client-to-server.html